# How to change a static sms message to dynamic

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have created an app that automatically sends sms for certain condition. Here is my code:

```
if(isNumberExist)//+923137737497
{
    //---display the new SMS message---
    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min  = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    date = String.format("%d/%d/%d",calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) );
    smsTime = String.format("%d:%d", hour,min);
    String[] numbers ;//= {"15555215558","15555215554"};
    db = database.getReadableDatabase();
    numbers= database.getNumbers(db, body);
    boolean loc = database.getSmsLocation(db, body);        
    db.close();

    if(loc)
    {       
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        String time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+ ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        //This is what I want to change. I mean I want that user can set a custom message instead of BUS TRAVELLING TIME IS xxxxx.
        String message = "Bus Travelling time is ";
        db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            database.insert_sms_data(numbers[i],message,date,smsTime, db);
            sender.sendSMS1(numbers[i],message + time);

            //Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent to "+numbers[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        /* code... */   
    }

    /* code... */   
}
```

As stated in the comments: **I want that user can set a custom message instead of BUS TRAVELLING TIME IS xxxxx.**

Comment: Do you mean you want to develop a UI interface for that? What have you tried thus far? Show us the code of your layout and the code of your activity. Where are you getting stuck? Are you able to run "hello world" on Android at the very least?

Comment: i have created a seperate class and layout for user to enter custom msg. but im unable to fetch that custom msg from database

Comment: Here is a tutorial I think you should follow: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html It's a tutorial about creating a Notepad application. It will teach you how to use SQLite and to how to retrieve data from it. Also, if you still have trouble with the Java language, I recommend that you go through these exercises online: http://codingbat.com/java